# How to stop Postfix from adding an extra Recipient in email headers?

Tags: postfix

We're using postfix together with osCommerce to send order notification emails.
Some of our emails are being flagged as spam, which looks to be because of a duplicate "To:" field in the email headers.
One of the "To:" lines (the one farther down) is being generated by the ecommerce checkout process, and the other seems to be coming from postfix.

How can we configure postfix to stop adding extraneous recipient addresses to our email headers?
Below is part of an order notification email header as an example:

```
Received: by name.host.com (Postfix, from userid 999) id 999999999999; Thu, 28 Jul 2022 09:22:21 -0400 (EDT)<br>
To: email@domain.com<br>
Subject: Order Number: 9999 - Store Name<br>
From: Name1 <no-reply@storedomain.com><br>
To: Name2 <email@domain.com><br>
MIME-Version: 1.0<br>
X-Mailer: osCommerce<br>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"<br>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit<br>
```

Thank you!

Comment: fix the application to properly format the header? See [name-addr definition in RFC5322](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322#section-3.4) on how display name and address should be unambiguously formatted.

Answer (score 0):

You must replace in your oscommerce the email.php and mime.php files found in the catalog/includes/classes and catalog/admin/includes/classes folders with a more recent version.
Download a recent version of: osCommerce 2.3.4 with Bootstrap
this is fine:
https://github.com/gburton/CE-Phoenix/tree/1.0.4.0